# Finding a solution for $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let
>
> $$K = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1 \}$$
>
> Prove that $\mbox{Span}(K) = \mathbb R^3$.

How can I solve this and find the vectors that will fit it?

Comment: Pick three solutions almost randomly $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. Then show that they span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: "Sp" denote Span.  @user647486 thanks but I'm looking for a general solution, it's a good guess since it's true but what if it's another equation such that i cant guess ?

Comment: Not everything in mathematics is a halting algorithm. The only way that the span is not the whole space is if $K$ is contained in a plane, or a line, or the origin. Since it is not, we just pick $3$ (the dimension of the space) points in it and check if they are not contained in a plane.

Comment: Can you state the problem in general that you want to be solved?

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson I assume that problem, in general, is how to solve equations like this.  for example if it was $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ then it's easy it's like homogenous system. but here it's different since if I try to solve it as I would do with the homogenous system then I get only 2 vectors.(i know it's not the way to solve it, just mention).@user647486 thanks then I guess I kind of has my answer.

Comment: @OO1 What is the span of a set? How is this linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

First, we observe that in order to show $Span(K)=\mathbb{R}^3$, it is enough to find three linearly independent vectors in $Span(K)$. This is because $Span(K)$ must be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence, if we find three linearly independent vectors in $Span(K)$, then $Span(K)$ must have dimension at least 3, which would directly imply $Span(K)=\mathbb{R}^3$, since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the only subspace of itself that has dimension 3.

Certainly if the standard basis were in $Span(K)$, we would be done. So we will start with the standard basis and slowly adjust our basis to fit our needs. Clearly $e_1:=(1,0,0)$ is in $K$, and likewise $e_2:=(0,1,0)$ is also in $K$. Unfortunately we see that $e_3=(1,0,0)$ is not in $K$. So we will try to adjust this vector such that it satisfies $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$, and is still linearly independent from $e_1$ and $e_2$. We can see that as long as $1$ remains in the $z$-coordinate, the vector must be linearly independent from $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then, we may freely adjust the $x$ and $y$ coordinate so that the $(x,y,1)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. Substitute $1$ for $z$ and the problem is reduced to finding $x^2+y^2=2$. Then we see that we may let $x=1$ and $y=1$, such that our final vector in the basis is $(1,1,1)$. Then, we see that we have a basis $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(1,1,1)$ in $K$ that spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence $Span(K)=\mathbb{R}$.